# Why $\aleph_0$ and $c$ are unequal transfinite cardinals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I recently started to learn about set theory and cardinals, and in the book that I'm using says that since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable and $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, we have $\aleph_0<c$, where $\aleph_0$ is the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$ (and also $\mathbb{Q}$) and $c$ is the cardinal number of $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, my problem is with the next sentence that follows from the theorem:

> **Theorem:** Let $S$ be a set. If $S$ is finite, then $|S|<\aleph_0$.

The book says:

> Thus **Theorem** implies that $\aleph_0$ and $c$ are unequal transfinite cardinals.

and I don't understand why. The theorem is about finite sets and $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are infinite, how are the two statements related?

Comment: Please give a reference to the book.

Comment: The two statements are not related. You must have misunderstood the book.

Comment: @TonyK: be fair: not every book is perfect! But, we can't say for sure until the OP gives the reference.

Comment: The book is Analysis with an introduction to proof by Steven Lay

Comment: @TonyK it says exactly what I wrote in the post.

Comment: @Verktaj: well, you left out the important part! See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what the book says:

> It is customary to denote the cardinal number of $\Bbb R$ by
>   $\mathcal{c}$, for continuum. Since $\Bbb Q\subseteq \Bbb R$, we have
>   $\aleph_0 \le \mathcal{c}$. In fact, since $\Bbb Q$ is countable and
>   $\Bbb R$ is uncountable, we have $\aleph_0<\mathcal{c}$. Thus Theorem
>   8.15(e) implies that $\aleph_0$ and $\mathcal{c}$ are unequal transfinite cardinals.

So the fact that $\aleph_0$ and $\mathcal{c}$ are *unequal* is already implied by $\aleph_0<\mathcal{c}$. What Theorem 8.15(e) tells us is that $\aleph_0$ and $\mathcal{c}$ are *transfinite*.

Comment: Just as the title indicated, it's watered down math.

Comment: Ahh ok. Now I understand that. Thanks